# iBeacon using Particle. Proximity triggers not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, ibeacon

I have the particle ibeacon working entering and exiting a region. I leave my house it says be safe, I come home and it greets me. I have the table set up so when I am unknown, far, near and immediate the appropriate responses tell me on my cell. I am using this switch

```
switch (proximity) {
        case CLProximityUnknown:
            return @"unknown";
            NSLog(@"This is the cell talking");
            break;
        case CLProximityImmediate:
            return @"Immediate";
            NSLog(@"This is immediate cell talking");
            break;
        case CLProximityNear:
            return @"Near";
            break;
        case CLProximityFar:
            return @"Far";
        default:
            break;
}
```

This works perfect. So in my main view controller I added this

```
-(void)actionForProximity:(CLProximity)proximity
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

    switch (proximity) {
        case CLProximityImmediate:
            notification.alertBody = @"You are in immediate danger!";
            notification.soundName = @"Default";
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
            NSLog(@"You are in immediate proximity to the beacon");
            break;
        case CLProximityNear:
            notification.alertBody = @"You are very near";
            notification.soundName = @"Default";
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
            NSLog(@"You are near the beacon");
            break;
        case CLProximityFar:
            notification.alertBody = @"Where are you going, you may get lost";
            notification.soundName = @"Default";
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
            NSLog(@"You are far from the beacon");
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

However it doesnt seem to cause a trigger at all. I used a break point and it doesnt seem to reach the method at all. I really want to use the proximity to trigger pop ups or in app controller etc... Any help would be so appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: unfortunately I am not using Estimote beacons, so only the ios framework will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch (proximity ) should be in your delegate method.

```
-(void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager
     didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
            inRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region
```

DidRangeBeacons need an array of beacons.

The method

> [self.beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region]

returns you the array you need and should be in the `ViewDidAppear`.

The delegate method is triggered every 20ms i think.

Hope this can help you.

( I m using Estimote SDK )